# CSS : Overflow-x: hidden, Overflow-y: visible in a carousel with dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my problem. I have a carousel that act like a menu also. When the amount of tabs is higher than the space of width available on your browser, the carousel-controls appears. Everything works fine. But I added as well a dropdown menu on each tabs and here is the thing. If I put overflow:visible, we can see the tabs sliding in and out of the div, which is very ugly.

If I put overflow:hidden, the slider works fine, but then, I can't see anymore my dropdown menu since they are hidden vertically as well. I tried to put overflow-y: visible and overflow-x:hidden but this won't work because if the "x" is visible, it will be considered as auto if the "y" is different. In other words, my slider works, but there is a scroll bar added to show my dropdown, which is very ugly.

I saw on another post to wrap it around a larger container, and I only hide the "x" while my "y" will fall back into the larger container. I can not do that since my carousel will break if the structure is not maintained.

So my question is : How can I do so that my slider looks good (we don't see the tabs sliding in and out) as well as my dropdown menu is showed up!

Here is the link if you want to check this out : https://decktogo.com/pages/downloads_user-manual_brochures

On large screen, you won't see anything wrong. Resize your browser window so that the width of it is around 380px. The slider will come in play and you will see the mess.

If you want my code, you can right click and inspect my website page to look at all the code there.

Thank you for your help,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Unfortunately, it didn't seem to have a good answer for that. So I did an overflow-x: hidden so that my carousel works fine. To solve the dropdown problem, I put a height:400px with margin-bottom:-300px which result in the good final looking with all what it supposed to be. It is just unfortunate that overflow-x and overflow-y doesn't work in that way.

```css
.download .carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel { 
  margin:0 40px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  width: auto;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom:-300px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.download .carousel-inner{
  overflow: initial;
}
```